# Lazarus messagebox: how to localize buttons

Tags: lazarus, freepascal

I want to localize buttons of `MesssageBox`, `MessageDlg`, `InputQuery`, etc.
I see `resourcestring` exist for this in `lclstrconsts`: "OK"/"Cancel".... but I want to set button strings using asssignments.

How to do it?

I need it on Win32. I see that German/Rus OS shows En buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it is done for `MessageDlg`: http://delphi.xcjc.net/viewthread.php?tid=47562.

Variables with `rs` prefix should be defined.

Other components could be localized the same way.

Comment: I first need `Application.MessageBox` - do you have an example?

Answer (score 1):

There are several articles in the wiki about localization:

[Translating/Internationalization/Localization](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Lazarus_Documentation#Translating.2FInternationalization.2FLocalization)

In short:

1. Set "Enable i18n" at the project options -> i18n, set PO Output Directory (`locale` for example)
2. Recompile project
3. Copy created `yourproject.po` file to `yourproject.de.po`, `yourproject.it.po` and so on for desired languages into the same directory.
4. Copy to `locale` directory of your project `*.po` files from `lazarus/lcl/languages` to translate LCL.
5. Add unit `LCLTranslator` to the `uses` clause of your main form.
6. Call `SetDefaultLang('it');` somewhere to set desired translation (Italian in this example). Check is all Ok by inspecting `GetDefaultLang` function result.

Note that (3) is required.

You may find ready to use POs in other thirdparty libraries if any.